# Nested express app use does not work

Tags: node.js, express

When i am doing nested express apps, nested app `use` does not work

```
var app = express();
var localApp = express();
app.use('/pdf-exporter', PDFExporterModule());


function PDFExporterModule(app) {
    localApp.use(function(req, res, next) {
        //this code never execute !!!!!!
        next();
    });
    localApp.get('/subpath/:userId', function() {...});
    return localApp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localApp` doesn't have a value when you first call `PDFExporterModule()`.  Move `var localApp=express()` up, or better yet, don't define local app outside of `PDFExporterModule`.

Also, it's good practice to leave all your `var` statements at the top.  Variable hoisting makes `localApp` exists and is undefined right at the top of your script.  It gets its value though where you have `var localApp=express()` below.

Comment: sorry it was copy/paste from another file so this works fine. Edited main question